# Trying to make a class into a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, multidimensional-array

I have created a class called Resources, within this class is the constructor and the relevant get and set methods. This provided the functionality I needed at the time.
Now, however, using Swing, I want to display a table using the information stored. 
I have been using the Object class to do this, and it provides the same information in the table. But, I want to use the Resource to store and get this data from so that many users can access using different classes or threads. This is where I get stuck, as I am unable to populate the Resources array as I did with the Object.

Any advice on how to solve this, or perhaps a better solution, would be greatly appreciated.

```
Object[][] resources = {{"Resource 1", 1, 1, 0, true},
          {"Resource 2", 2, 1, 1, true}, {"Resource 3", 3, 1, 2, false},
          {"Resource 4", 4, 1, 3, false}};
```

Above, this is the Object array that I am currently using.

```
Resources[][]res = new Resources[4][5];
```

Above, this the Resources array I've tried to implement but it won't let me continue in adding the data - it requests Resources rather than the data I have

Comment: That is because the Resources object does not take the values that you are trying to store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom table model and go directly to a List of Resources to return data for specific cells. Something like this:

```
public class ResourceModel extends DefaultTableModel{

   List<Resource> resources;


   public Object getValueAt(int row, int col){
      Resource resource = resources.get(row);

      if(col == 0){
         return resource.getName();
      }
      else if(col == 1){
         return resource.getOtherThing();
      }
      //so on

   }

   public int getRowCount(){
     return resources.size();
   }

}
```

More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: Thanks. The only thing is it is now saying that resources.size has a null point exception...

Comment: Obviously you have to initialize the resources variable, presumably through a constructor. I have no idea how your code is connected (since you didn't provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), so the best we can do is point you to the general idea.

Comment: After a bit of tinkering, got it working pretty perfectly, most with thanks to your code. Thankyou very much!